# _BaseModel__view_look_dom_arch

Tags: python, xml, module, odoo

Need to clafiry what is this error.?unable to install my own devbeloped module.?
rechecked my view XML file also.can't find any error

```
  File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 1776, in __view_look_dom
    xarch, xfields = relation.__view_look_dom_arch(cr, user, f, view_id, ctx)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_BaseModel__view_look_dom_arch'
2013-03-21 09:19:32,668 3683 ERROR bpl_db openerp.tools.convert: Parse error in /home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/addons/bpl/bpl_view.xml:276: 
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="bpl_work_offer_form">
            <field name="name">bpl.work.offer.form</field>
            <field name="model">bpl.work.offer</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="bpl_work_offer" version="7.0">
                    <sheet>

..............................................

  File "/home/priyan/Software/openerp-7.0-20130309-002120/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 144, in wrapper
    raise except_osv(inst.name, inst.value)
except_osv: ('ValidateError', u'Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!')
2013-03-21 09:19:32,680 3683 INFO bpl_db werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [21/Mar/2013 09:19:32] "POST /web/dataset/call_button HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: I think this problem now solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue with my sequence.xml file & onetomany mapping in model class
& do somechanges to **openerp**.py file as per version 07

then issue now sorted..

ALL THE CREDITS NEED TO GO TO **user1576199**
Who, directly involved & helped me to correct all the issues in my codes